# Get info from MySQL added in specific time

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, row

I've created a script to receive all rows added to sql in specific time and set variables getting values from specific columns in each new record (row). This is what i did:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$host='localhost';
$user='username';
$password='password';
$dbname='racheaqui';

$connection=mysql_connect('localhost:/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock',$user,$password) or die ("connection failed");

mysql_select_db($dbname, $connection);

$query = "SELECT * FROM store WHERE date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 20 MINUTE;";

$result=mysql_query($query, $conexao);

if ($result){

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
$email=$row['email_contact'];
$name=$row['name'];
$phone=$row['phone_contact'];
}
}

#if (!empty($name)) {
print_r("The user ".$name." with phone ".$phone." and e-mail: ".$email." has created an account in the system.\n");
mysql_close($connection);
#}
?>
```

But with this code, I will only set the variables with the values from last row. What I plan is to set like: $variable1, $variable2, $variable3, $variableX. Where $variableX is the number of rows added (that I've received in array format).

Could you please give me some help? Im newbie in php coding, but believe me, I've really tried hard and also searched in google and in stackoverflow's database before ask it here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to use pdo ,it's easy mysql is  depreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $email=$row['email_contact'];
    $name=$row['name'];
    $phone=$row['phone_contact'];
}
```

You are *overwriting* `$email`, `$name`, and `$phone` for each record. You can either collect them in separate arrays like this:

```
$emails = array();
$names = array();
$phones = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $emails[]=$row['email_contact'];
    $names[]=$row['name'];
    $phones[]=$row['phone_contact'];
}
```

Or Create one big array with the data for each store:

```
$data = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $data[] = array(
        'email' => $row['email_contact'],
        'name' => $row['name'],
        'phone' => $row['phone_contact']
    );
}
```

Alternatively, you can put your `print_r()` inside the loop like this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $email=$row['email_contact'];
    $name=$row['name'];
    $phone=$row['phone_contact'];
    print_r("The user ".$name." with phone ".$phone." and e-mail: ".$email." has created an account in the system.\n");
}
```

Comment: Great, @mopo922. In the first case, how can I extract the value from each array?

Comment: `$emails[0]`, `$emails[1]`, etc. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: @Marcelo Stop the... ?

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting your variables each time you go through the while loop. Try putting your print statement inside the while loop, like
    print $email . "
";
    print $name . "
";
    print $phone . "
";
rather than using print_r

You might want to put a counter in your loop and print that too.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysql_num_rows` if you would like to know the number of selected rows.

```
if ($result)
{
    $nr_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $email=$row['email_contact'];
        $name=$row['name'];
        $phone=$row['phone_contact'];
        print "The user ".$name." with phone ".$phone." and e-mail: ".$email." has created an account in the system.\n";
    }
    print "Accounts created the last 20 minutes: ".$nr_rows; 
}
```